# Storing duplicate data in MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a table with all registered `members`, with columns like `uid`, `username`, `last_action_time`.

I also have a table that keeps track of who has been `online` in the past 5 minutes. It is populated by a cronjob by pulling data from `members` with `last_action_time` being less than 5 minutes ago.

**Question**: Should my `online` table include `username` or no? I'm asking this because I could `JOIN` both tables to obtain this data, but I could store the `username` in the `online` table and not have to join. My concern is that I will have duplicate data stored in two tables, and that seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't run into performance issues, DO NOT denormalize. There is a good saying "normalize until it hurts, denormalize until it works". In your case, it works with normalized schema (users table joined). And data bases are designed to handle huge amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is called denormalization. I mean that sometimes for quick select query we have to duplicate some data across tables. In this case I believe that this one is good choice if you have a lot of data in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

You just hit a very valid question: when does it make sense to duplicate data ?

I could rewrite your question as: when does it make sense to use a cache. Caches need maintenance, you need to keep them up to date yourself and they use up some extra space (although negligible in this case). But they have a pro: performance increase.

In the example you mentioned, you need to see if that performance increase is actually worth it and if it outweighs the additional work of having and maintaining a cache.

My gut feeling is that your database isn't gigantic, so joining every time should take a minimal amount of effort from the server, so I'd go with that.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store the username in the online table. There shouldn't be any performance issue . Just use a join every time to get the username.

Plus, you don't need the online table at all, why don't you query only the users with an last_action_time < 5 min from the members table?

Comment: Because indexing a time is inefficient. Also online table can store information that is not stored in the general members table, such as their current IP, browser, if they're on a mobile device etc. etc

Answer (score 0):

A user ID would be an integer (AKA 4 bytes). A username (i would imagine is up to 16 bytes). How many users? How ofter a username changes? These are the questions to consider.

I wold just store the username. I wou;ld have though once the username is registered it is fixed for the duration.

**If is difficult to answer these questions without a little background - performance issues are difficult to think about when the depth and breath, usabge etc. is not known.**